# Rendering a Wicket component

Tags: html, rendering, wicket

I have a Wicket panel that is attached to a Page. I need to obtain rendered HTML code that  the panel generates. I need the same HTML that the panel generates to output that was sent to the browser. I don't what the HTML from the whole page.

My panel is a read-only so it doesn't matter if the output is re-generated.

```java
private MyPanel myPanel;

public void onIntialize() {
   super.onInitialize();
   add(myPanel = new MyPanel());
}

new AjaxLink() {
  public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    String myPanelHtml = // obtain html somehow from myPanel
    // do stuff with myPanelHtml
  }
}
```

Are things different if I need rendered HTML from a component that is not a panel? A component that does not provide the markup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Wicket 6.7.0 it can be acomplished easily with

`ComponentRenderer.render(Component c)`

From wicket page:

> Render a page or component to a String
>
> One of the issues that keeps propping up on the user lists is the
>   ability to render a page or component to a String so that you can use
>   Wicket to render HTML email messages. Now you can use
>   ComponentRenderer to actually do so without having to resort to other
>   less obvious methods.
>
> ComponentRenderer exposes two methods: renderComponent and renderPage
>   and they do exactly what their names suggest. Happy emailing!

Although is intended for mailing, you can use it for other purposes as well, of course

Answer (score 0):

Based on jordeu's answer and Wicket wiki I made this. It doesn't require modifying component component hierarchy, but in my case the panel is already a part of the page.

However I am bit concerned about changing application settings and using non-public parts of Wicket API.

```java
public static StringResponse getRenderedResponse(final Component container) {
    // store rendered markup to different place
    final Response originalResponse = RequestCycle.get().getResponse();
    StringResponse stringResponse = new StringResponse();
    RequestCycle.get().setResponse(stringResponse);

    // disable "component must be rendered only once per request" -check
    boolean originalComponentCheck = container.getApplication().getDebugSettings().getComponentUseCheck();
    container.getApplication().getDebugSettings().setComponentUseCheck(false);

    try {
        // prepareForRender() is not part of public Wicket API!!
        container.prepareForRender();
        container.render();
        container.afterRender();
    } finally {
        // restore RequestCycle and checks
        container.getApplication().getDebugSettings().setComponentUseCheck(originalComponentCheck);
        RequestCycle.get().setResponse(originalResponse);
    }
    return stringResponse;
}
```

Usage:

```java
new AjaxLink() {
  public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    StringResponse response = getRenderedResponse(myPanel);
    String myPanelHtml = response.toString();
    // do stuff with myPanelHtml
}
```